# Some icons are missing after install ark theme

Tags: unity, icons, themes, unity-tweak-tool

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 and also I installed  ark theme and ark icons. I select them using Unity Tweak Tool.

The problem is that some programs lost their icons. I mean, when I open the terminal, for example, a question mark appears in the location of the terminal icon in the behaviour.

I tried to switch the theme and the icons and restore all default options. I reinstalled ubuntu but when I do what I mention before, the problem come back. Also I tried to reinstall and restart unity and ubuntu desktop. Nothing works.

Does anyone knows why happens that? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ran into the same exact problem. After searching online I did find the solution:

Navigate to `/usr/share/icons/Arc-Icons`. You should see a file named `index.theme`.

We need to edit that file using a text editor (nano, gedit, etc), however we will need root access first. For simplicity's sake, just right-click anywhere in that folder and select "open terminal" and you should get a terminal in the same directory (`/usr/share/icons/arc-icons`).

Next, type in `sudo nano index.theme`, and provide your password. It should open up a text editor. Scroll down until you see this part:

```
[Icon Theme]  
Name=Arc  
Inherits=Moka,Adwaita,gnome,hicolor  
Comment=Arc Icon theme
```

Now, the line `Inherits=` is the one you want to edit, as  basically it tells the system what icons to use if Arc is missing any icons. Change it so it looks like this:

```
[Icon Theme]  
Name=Arc  
Inherits=ubuntu-mono-dark  
Comment=Arc Icon theme
```

This will set Arc to use the default Ubuntu icons for any missing icons, which as we've discovered it's missing several (Additional Drivers, Terminal, Software Updates, etc). Once you've edited the file, save and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> if you're using nano), then reboot your system. You'll notice that you still have Arc icons except for the missing ones, they revert back to default icons. Feel free to substitute `ubuntu-mono-dark` for your preferred icons.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could install the Moka icon theme to fix the problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moka/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install moka-icon-theme
```

go to https://snwh.org/moka to see more details or if you want to install on a different distro